# HIbernate Maven project: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, derby

I am working on a JPA tutorial and running into issues when trying to unit test. I am working with Apache Derby and Hibernate.
Here is my sample code files;

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>org.agonical.book.pojo.Book</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation-action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation-target" value="database-and-scripts"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/chapter4DB;create=true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="insert.sql"/>
        <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**Test.class**

```
private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
private EntityManager entityManager;
private EntityTransaction transaction;

@Before
public void initEntityManager() throws Exception {
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
}

@After
public void closeEntityManager() throws Exception {
    if(entityManager != null){
        entityManager.close();
    }
}

@Test
public void shouldFindJavaEE7Book() throws Exception {
    Book book = entityManager.find(Book.class, 1001L);
    assertEquals("Beginning Java EE 7", book.getTitle());
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
  <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
  <version>10.11.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Error when unit testing**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named test
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at org.agonical.book.BookIT.<clinit>(BookIT.java:19)
... 21 more
```

The `persistence.xml` is located in the `src/test/resources/META-INF` dir. I did have the test `persistence-unit` in the one `persistence.xml` file in `src/main/resources/META-INF` dir.
Each ends with the same result. I have been doing numerous research online and from what I can see I am doing everything correctly and don't understand why this is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Exception message states "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named test". I don't see a definition for "test" anywhere either.

Comment: In the first line of the test class I define a `EntityManagerFactory` stating to use `test`

Comment: I see that, but that line expects something by the name of "test" to be defined in the persistence.xml.

Comment: ah sorry no I was doing a test where I matched the persistence-unit names, I will update the samples

Comment: Why the negative mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>5.0.0.Final</version> // or whatever version you use
</dependency>
```

to your pom dependencies.

Currently you have only API.